# Magit pushing / pulling show progress

Tags: magit

I'm missing some visual indication of the push / pull progress. After executing the appropriate command, `magit` prints

> Pushing to domain.tld:repo.git

however, no further indication of the progress is given. On a slow network connection or if the data to be transmitted is large, the process can take quite some time, hence, it would be nice if `magit` could give some indication of progress.

Naturally the `*magit-process*` buffer contains `git`'s own progress indication but how do you tell `magit` to pass the relevant part through to the echo area?

Even better would be if the progress indicator is added to the mode line, thus allowing the user to close the `magit-status` buffer and continue working while `git` is doing the heavy lifting.

**Edit:** I'm not looking for indication that `magit` is pushing / pulling, I know that because I just hit `P`/`F`. I want to see at which stage of pushing / pulling it is (i.e. (un)packing, transmitting) and how much of that action it already did.

Remember, if you run `git` through the terminal it'll print something like

> Pushing to domain.tld:repo.git
>   Counting objects: 29, done.
>   Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 249.80 KiB | 28.00 KiB/s, done.
>   Total 15 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   To domain.tld:repo.git
>      5436bd0..d9ec32a  master -> master
>   updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'

[obviously this is a snapshot of the dynamic output]. I would like that progress to be displayed from within emacs.

**Edit2:** Opened feature request on [github](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1527)

Comment: [meta discussion about the topicality of this question](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/q/88/221)

Answer (score 7):

That feature has existed forever. But I have to admit that I never noticed that either, and only know about it because I stumbled into the implementation :-)

When an asynchronous process is running you will see e.g. `Magit git update` instead of just `Magit` in the mode-line.

Comment: I see that I did not express clear enough what I'm looking for. Please read the edit I've added to my post.

Comment: I see. May I ask why you need to know at what stage the command is?

Comment: Please open a feature request.

Comment: Please note that I have decided not to implement the requested feature.

Answer (score 1):

While still not a progress indicator, the following enhancements in Magit 2.12 are relevant:

> - The mode line process indicator, displayed in the mode line when Git
>     is run for side-effects, is now more visible than before, and is
>     additionally used to highlight process errors.
>
>   New face `magit-mode-line-process` is applied to the mode line
>     process indicator to improve the visibility of pending asynchronous
>     processes (in particular), as Magit remains responsive after
>     initiating such commands (for instance fetching or rebasing), but
>     will not update its buffers until the process has completed, which
>     might take longer than anticipated.  Customize this face if you wish
>     to make this indicator more (or less) visible.  #3284
>
>   If the Git process returns an error, the mode line process indicator
>     is no longer removed, and new face `magit-mode-line-process-error`
>     is applied to highlight the error status.  Details of the error from
>     the process buffer are also provided as a tool-tip.  The error
>     indicator will remain visible in the mode line until a magit buffer
>     is refreshed.  If you do not want errors to be indicated in the mode
>     line, customize the `magit-process-display-mode-line-error` user
>     option.  #3297

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-face` <kbd>RET</kbd> `magit-mode-line-process` <kbd>RET</kbd>

If you give this face a high-contrast foreground colour, you are certain to notice whenever a git process is taking a long time to complete.